# Picking a database solution for an Excel UI?

Tags: database, excel, ms-access

I am building a small application on Excel using VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) Visual Basic and currently building the UI on excel and the functions with in it. However, the application itself will start to store data as it is being used.. what is the best way of storing this data? I don't want to store it in Excel.

The Excel workbook, that is programmed on Visual Studio will be distributed to a bunch of people on different computers and then I'll send out the occasional update using the ClickOnce deployment method - so storing data on the actual workbook will just get over-written.

I was thinking of having a Access database in the back-end that will store all the data and I can just continue to update the Excel UI as we go down the road; but a few issues around this:

- How safe is it? I need to store a very simple username/password table as well. This is a simply to 'login' to the Excel solution but if it's a Access database; I thought of password protecting the entire database.
- What if the end user does not have Access installed?

I was reading about a MySQL solution too but my 'skills' are limited to Access/Excel and VBA and only now starting to learn VSTO to build this application; so MySQL would be another learning curve to undertake.

PS: :A simple table structure offered by Access would be fine, because the entire data set per Excel workbook won't ever get more than 1-2k rows.

Answer (score 0):

If the "bunch of people" will be reading and writing to tables in a shared back-end database then using an Access database would likely be a perfectly acceptable solution provided that the "bunch of people" is not too large. A practical limit for the number of concurrent users hitting a common Access back-end depends on a number of factors, but *generally speaking:*

- 10 to 12 concurrent users is often cited as the point where things will start to slow down, and
- 25 concurrent users is considered by many to be the practical upper limit.

> What if the end user does not have Access installed?

If they didn't already have Access then they would need to install the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255).